# Initialization - Why must I use self in order to set a variable's value?

Tags: swift

I was working with initializers in Swift and was wondering why self was needed before the names of each variable in a case like this:

```
import UIKit

class Vehicle {


var model:String
var speed:Int
var year:Int

init(model: String, speed: Int, year: Int) {

    self.model = "null"
    self.speed = 0
    self.year = 0000


}
}
```

But is not needed in a case like this where init has no parameters:

```
import UIKit

class Vehicle {


var model:String
var speed:Int
var year:Int

init() {

    model = "null"
    speed = 0
    year = 0000


}
}
```

Is there a difference between the two different setups and if so, in what circumstances should each be used? Thanks.

Comment: `model`, and `year` should probably be `let` constants. There's no situation in which a car changes its model or its year of production

Comment: @Alexander: you need to hang out more with used car dealers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `self`, how is Swift supposed to know that you mean the instance variable `model` as opposed to the parameter of the same name?

You only need to do this when you have local variables (or parameters) that have the same name as a variable in an outer scope.

This may have been a little more obvious if you actually tried to use those parameters (your code example just ignores them). Then you'd write something like

```
model = model
speed = speed
year = year
```

which you have to admit looks problematic.